# Need to remove character from a string in C

Tags: c, string

I need to write a program that takes a string and a character as input, then removes all of that character from the string. The catch is I need to use the same string to print the output. The code I've done so far doesn't remove anything and I don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 25


int main(void)
{
    char string[MAX_LENGTH];
    int character;
    int count, i, j;

    printf("Enter a string (max length 25): ");
    fgets(string, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);
    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf("%d", character);

    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++){
        while (string[i] == character){
            count ++;
            for (j = i; string[j] != '\0'; j++){
                string[j] = string[j+1];
            }
            string[j] = '\0';
        }

    }
    printf("Output String: %s", string);
    printf("Output Count: %d\n", count);
}
```

Comment: `%d` is used to input an integer. `scanf` is taking a pointer.

Comment: and what does the debugger show when you step through?

Comment: Enable your compiler all warnings to catch simple mistakes like `int character;
...    scanf("%d", character);`

Comment: The loop is also slightly wrong, if the target character appears more than once in succession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue in your code is easily spotted by the compiler:

```
$ clang char.c
char.c:15:17: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
scanf("%d", character);
       ~~   ^~~~~~~~~
 1 warning generated.
```

If you take the address of `character` by replacing it with `&character` your code will compile but still not work correctly. First, replace `%d` by `%c` since you want a `char`, not an `int`, and update the definition accordingly (`char character`). Then, if you only need to output the input string minus any occurrences of the specified character you can get this by simply iterating over the characters one by one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 25


int main(void)
{
    char string[MAX_LENGTH];
    char character;
    int count, i, j;

    printf("Enter a string (max length 25): ");
    fgets(string, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);
    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf("%c", &character);
    printf("%s", "Output String: ");
    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if (string[i] != character) {
            putchar(string[i]);
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("Output Count: %d\n", count);
}
```

Output:

```
$ clang char.c -o char && ./char
Enter a string (max length 25): arra
Enter a character: r
Output String: aa
Output Count: 2
```

Comment: Yes this worked a treat, thank you very much. Still very new to this lol.